# How to reference Windows specific assemblies like System.Device in a .NET Standard Library?

Tags: .net, .net-standard-2.0

I have a project with:

```
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

and it uses System.Device.dll as reference.

Migrating all .net 4.6.1 class libs to a .NET Standard lib I asked myself how can I add the System.Device.dll to a .NET Standard 2.0 project?

Any Idea?

Comment: Support for WinRT contracts has been removed from .NET 6.  The new way is to generate an interop assembly from the contract metadata file, not unlike the way it is done with legacy COM type libraries.  It is rumored that such an assembly can be referenced in a .NETStandard project.  The outline of the procedure [is here](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/blob/master/docs/usage.md), the doc landing page [is here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/platform/csharp-winrt/)

Comment: Thanks for your adivse Hans. Was the "It is rumored..." comment irony?